# Sending parameters from Form To Url.Action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to pass data from `text field` to `URL.action`.

This `DIV` is used by my ajax, to refresh it whenever the button inside that `DIV` is pressed. Everything works great. Thing is I need to pass some parameters with that `URL.action to controller` too. Parameters that are in `textfields or dropboxes` in the same View. How can I do that?

**My div:**

```
 <div id="mylist" data-source-url="@Url.Action("lentele", new { status = "good"})">
```

**Dropbox I want to take the chosen value from:**

```
@Html.DropDownList("status", new SelectList(ViewBag.Status, "name", "name"), "Status", new { @class = "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle", style = "width:120px;" })
```

In example if I write `status="good"` in parameters everything works, and I get what I want. But how can I set to get status from `DropDownList`?

data-source-url is used as attribute to get url here:

```
<script>
    function ajaxifyGridMvc(gridContainerSelector, successCallback) {
        $(gridContainerSelector).on("click", ".grid-header a, .grid-pager li a",
            function (event) {
                var $grid_container = $(event.delegateTarget);

                var baseUrl = $grid_container.attr("data-source-url");
                var link = $(this).attr("href");
                $.get(baseUrl + link, function (data) {
                    if (data.Status <= 0) {
                        alert(data.Message);
                        return;
                    }
                    $grid_container.html(data);
                    if ($.isFunction(successCallback))
                        successCallback();
                });

                return false;
            });
    }
</script>
```

**Answer:**

Passing dynamical value to url.action is not possible.
So had to manage other way and I figured out that I could jsut change baseUrl and set parameters there.

It looks like:

```
$.get(baseUrl + link + "&slicplate="+ $("#slicplate").val()....
```

Comment: Where & How are you using `data-source-url`?

Comment: I'm using it as parameter where i set my url..

Comment: Please show rendered HTML - also in jQuery you use .data("source-url") instead of .attr("data-source-url")

Comment: which part of html u want to see?

Comment: `@Html.DropDownList`would have been useful

Comment: Ok,perhap i have a wrong answer.But all of you who understand answer from Justina Seliokaite.Look the title "Sending parameters from Form To Url.Action". Url.Action is server function to generate html string to client why "Sending parameters from Form To Url.Action"?? And with html and javascrit Justina Seliokaite who can understand clearly this thread?

Comment: There is answer, I assume that somebody understood that :)

Whats wrong with my question?

Sending parameters(which are, status, etc,etc) From form(since they are entered in a form, textbox) to URL.Action (which obiously is a function). You can use URL.Action to set parameters by creating them  like new {param1 = "", param2=""}.

Comment: And I'm not asking to offer me a Javascript code which would do that. @Satpal wanted to see that code thats why I added it. I wanted to know maybe there is some way passing parameters stricly in html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass parameters to you action methods using the `data` parameter of the `$.get()` method. For example if you need to pass 2 values to this method

```
public ActionResult DoSomething(string Name, int Category) {...
```

and you have the following html

```
<input type="text" id="Name" ... />
<select id="Category" ...>
  <option value="1">Category 1</option>
  <option value="2">Category 2</option>
  ...
</select>
```

and you wanted to pass the value of the textbox and the dropdown, you can use

```
var url = '@UrlAction("DoSomething", "YourControllerName")';
var name = $('#Name').val();
var category = $('#Category').val();
$.get(url, { Name: name, Category: category }, function (data) {
  // do something with the data returned by the action method
```